# How word дясна became десна?

Tags: этимология

The word evidently comes from PIE ***e̯dentsnea̯*** from ***e̯donts*** "tooth" from root ***e̯ed-*** "to bite". This should give "дясна" in Russian. Why "десна" then?

Comment: Perhaps it's a borrowing from the OCS _десна_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it should and it was - in Old Russian it was "дясна" up to XV century. In Ukrainian it is [still](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0) "ясна" which is the remnant of that form. In Belarusian it is "дзясна".

To my knowledge in almost all other Slavic languages, except Polish and including Church Slavonic, the form was with -e. My guess is that something similar to "aгнец"/"ягнёнок" had happend, it's just that in this particular case, the church slavonic form won.

Comment: May be, influence of the word десница "(right) hand" which had different origin (< ***decsnos*** "right")?

Comment: @Anixx, quite probably, though this should be verified. Also, there was a bunch of other words that coexisted in e/я form, like тѧтива or ıастрѧбъ.